# ActionMailer renders more then needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

**class UserMailer**

```
def notification_email(user, msg_body, msg_count)
    @user = user
    @msg_body = msg_body
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "New comments. #{msg_count}.")
  end
```

**notification_email.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>
<h1>You have new comments </h1>
<p>
  <ul>
   <%= @msg_body.each do |msg| %>
    <li><a href="<%= msg %>"><%= msg %></a></li>
   <% end %>
  </ul>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

For message body I pass to view array **msg_body**. In **mailcatcher** I can see the list of hrefs as I need. But also I see the array as plain text after the list. I really can't understand from where it goes.

Comment: is rails automatically appending a text version of the email body for non-html email clients?

Comment: it's separate view for plain text "notification_email.text.erb". but I try things without this file. have no any effect.

Comment: try changing `<%= @msg_body.each do |msg| %>` to `<% @msg_body.each do |msg| %>` - remove the equal from the each block

Comment: @house9 super! still have to learn a lot. it was the problem

Comment: ok - i added that as the answer, feel free to accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `<%= @msg_body.each do |msg| %>` to `<% @msg_body.each do |msg| %>` - remove the equal from the each block